# Why is it tha std::list::sort does not work?

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a `list<int>` with the content `3,2,1`.

After calling `std::list::sort()` on the list, the order of the integer content does not change. Why is this so?

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list, list1;

    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(3);

    list1.push_back(3);
    list1.push_back(2);
    list1.push_back(1);

    list1.sort();

    return list == list1;
}
```

In my code I keep getting false, why?

I looked at the content of the list before and after the call of the `sort()` function using visual studio intellisense and I observed that there was no change in the sort order, thus justifying the result of the equality test.

From the visual observation, using the intellisense, there was reason to believe the sort function did not work.

I changed the data structure to a vector so that I had

```
class Greaterthan : std::binary_function<int,int,bool> 
{
public:
    result_type operator()(first_argument_type first,second_argument_type second)
    {
        return (result_type)(first < second);
    }
}
```

Then, I re-wrote the code as

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list, list1;

    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(3);

    list1.push_back(3);
    list1.push_back(2);
    list1.push_back(1);

    list1.sort(Greaterthan());

    return list == list1;
}
```

But, the same thing happened. Why?

Comment: `Error: missing source code`

Comment: Who knows? We cant read mind. Be concrete. Post your code.

Comment: Line 42, there's a syntax error.

Comment: @Marco A should put this out of hold.

Comment: , @Gill Bates I think you should give it another look.

Comment: , @EdChum , I think you should see this.

Comment: , @LogicStuff. Perhaps you should take a look.

Comment: ,@A.S.H., Do take a look.

Comment: push_back results in the list or vector being in the order of the push_back, so the llist1.sort() compare should be the default less than. The if statement should be if (llist == llist1). You might want to use list1 and list2 for the names so it's easier to read by others. With the if statement fixed, the program ran ok for me.

Comment: Maybe _you_ should take a look. [It works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bb3e06fbf3dfdd6). Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @mindriot, it amazing that code you pointed to worked fine even with my compiler, I just wonder what is wrong. It is no different from what I have here.

Comment: I guarantee that it is not the compiler's fault. Post a proper [mcve] and show us how it fails.

Comment: It looks like you are returning 1 (failure) when the lists compare equals and 0 (success) otherwise.  So you get a failure because the sorted list/vector now matches the expected result.

Comment: @mindriot, I finally found the bug, thanks to you. Actually, the input to the function that manipulates the list objects are strings of sets  with comma seperated members.

Comment: @mindriot, I finally found the bug, thanks to you. Actually, the input to the function that manipulates the list objects are strings of sets  with comma seperated members. The function converts each integer int the set to from char to integer and pushes them into the list object. When, that was how it  was suppose to work, but the error was that the function lumps all the integer members of the set together and converts them into a single unsortable integer. That was why no sorting occurred because what I had in the list objects were single integers and not a set of integers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

So when you have something like this:

```
std::list<int> l;
l.push_back(4);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(1);
l.sort();
```

The list will look like: [1,2,4]

You should provide us your code to get an answer that is more detailed for your problem